# Want data from selected file by tapping particular button

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uibutton

I am new to iPhone and i am creating an iPhone app in which i am using simple text file as my database.
In firstView i have four UIButtons. I have four different text file.
What i want is when i select button1 then data from file1.txt will be load same as when i select button2 , button3 and button4 , data from file2 ,file3 ,file4 will be load respectively.

Something like this :

```
if(categoryVC.Quiz1btn isSelected == YES){
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
self.theQuiz = quizArray;
}
```

but this is not working.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add an (NSString*) filename attribut in your second viewController and pass the name of the selected file button as following in the fisrt view controller :

```
-(IBAction)selectFile1Action:(id)sender {
SecondViewController *scView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
scView.filename = @"file1";
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:scView animated:YES];
[scView release];
```

}

and so one ...

And in viewDidLoad function of the second view controller you add the following code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:filename ofType:@"txt"]; 
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]]; 
self.theQuiz = quizArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to create four functions on your Controller (IBAction) and link then with your view in Interface Builder.
The functions can be like that :

- (IBAction)selectFile1Action:(id)sender {
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"txt"];
  NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
  self.theQuiz = quizArray;
  }
- (IBAction)selectFile2Action:(id)sender {
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"file2" ofType:@"txt"];
  NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
  self.theQuiz = quizArray;
  }
- (IBAction)selectFile3Action:(id)sender {
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"file3" ofType:@"txt"];
  NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
  self.theQuiz = quizArray;
  }
- (IBAction)selectFile4Action:(id)sender {
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"file4" ofType:@"txt"];
  NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
  self.theQuiz = quizArray;
  }

Comment: but the buttons are in first view and i want data in second view.
So is it possible??